# What does \$\mathrm{I_{D25}}\$ imply in this MOSFET datasheet?

Tags: power, mosfet, power-electronics

1. Can someone help me in understanding the notation \$\mathrm{I_{D25}}\$ in the MOSFET [datasheet](https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/240/ixys_s_a0008598099_1-2273228.pdf)?
2. Why is it getting multiplied by 0.5 factor?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On page 1 of the linked datasheet,

[image: I_D25 is listed as being 64 A.]

This is the rated maximum current at a case temperature of 25 °C. They're using half of that, because you don't generally run a part at its rated maximum current--in particular, keeping the case temperature at 25 °C is pretty impractical.